# Instead of targetting a name ID, target an ID that increments with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (valueInput == jsyl) {
  var correctBtn = $('<button/>', {
 'class': 'btn btn-success buttonCorrect',
'type': 'button',
'id': 'CorrectIdCount'+CBC++
});
```

Note the ID, it gets incremented. Don't worry about the variable, I already declared that one (globally).

```
$('#CorrectIdCount').html(valueInput);
```

Question: How can I target the ID that is incrementing? I tried with the `#`, tried just `CBC`, as you can see tried it with the + too. Any idea?

Comment: *"+CBC++"* pretty bad idea.

Comment: Ideally you should prefix the ID so it doesn't start with a number, or some browsers won't find it.  Are you trying to target it later, or when it's created?

Comment: Hey Archer, back at it again? I'll adjust that then if that's better. I am trying to target it when it is created. Basically to give u a little idea: I have an input field, when you have the correct answer it should pop over to this green button, but keep the value. Tried doing this with the class, but the problem is: Whenever I target the class it will append the value I just wrote to all the green buttons with the same class. I am trying to keep them apart so each green button will keep it's own value. Thank you very much for the heads up. Editted the post to what seemed the most logical.

Comment: use the instance of the class in event handler which is `this`. Trying to work with dynamic ID's is a lot more work than working with class and instances

Comment: Just getting some clarity so we can help give suitable answers.  You know I like clarity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to change the value at the time you create the button there's no need to use a selector.  You can set the html value when you create the button, rather than create it, add it to the DOM and then select it from the DOM...

```
if (valueInput == jsyl) {
    var correctBtn = $('<button/>', {
        'class': 'btn btn-success buttonCorrect',
        'type': 'button',
        'id': "button" + CBC++,
        'html': valueInput
    });
}
```

Also, if you need to add a button handler you can use the instance you just created, like this...

```
correctBtn.on("click", function() {
    // add your click handler here
});
```

### Note

I added the `button` prefix to the button's id due to what I mentioned in the comment above.  Some browsers will fail when trying to select elements with an id that begins with a number, so that will resolve that potential issue and is just a good "to know".

Comment: Quick question tho: Is it possible to create a timer that evaluates the whether it's the right one or wrong one? Right now I use a "change". But I will have to manually move to another input field to let it evaluate.

Comment: Use `input` instead of `change`.  As you say, `change` only triggers when an input loses focus, but `input` will trigger for any change, including copy/paste type changes.  It's the best catch-all for inputs.